# Apparent bug with google maps v3 and Safari 5 antialiasing on os x

Tags: google-maps, safari, google-maps-api-3

I've found what appears to be a bug with the Google Maps V3 API and Safari 5 on OS X.

It's quite simple really. As soon as the map loads it kills the antialiasing on any positioned elements (relative, absolute of fixed).

Here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzyd/XXhky/3/ so you can try it for yourself.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could possibly sort this?

Thanks

EDIT: This seems to be fixed in the most recent version of Safari and/or Google Maps.

**EDIT2: Or maybe not.**

Comment: I have the same issue here. Very annoying.

Comment: Can you add -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); to any position elements and see if that works?

Comment: Returning to look at the jsFiddle, this seems to now be sorted, either by a newer version of Safari, or a newer version of google maps. Does anybody else still see it?

Comment: Definitely not fixed with latest Google Maps and Safari 5.1.7.

Comment: @dallen, You're right - it's back! I could have sworn it worked for me last time I checked. How depressing.